# What would the database schema of yelp or a review site look like?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, database-schema

I could use some help structuring a DB. I currently have a DB and a single table called listings with like 8 columns(name, contact, address...) that hold info about each organization.

Next I want to set up a review data structure to store and retrieve reviewer info (name userName, date commented, comments...).
These are my current  guesses at the problem...

1)A separate table for each organization

2)Separate column for each piece of reviewer data(so like 5 columns per business) in one giant table?

3)One table per piece of data (so one table for username, one table for comments...)?

The first one seems crazy(since if you had 500 entities then you have 500 table).

The second threw me a mysql error when I ran a php script I wrote to add like 200 entities*5 pieces of data (1000 columns). Dont quite remember the error, something like mysql: too many columns(when i looked it up, the reference said it was becasue I had added too many columns)

The third seems like that's probably the right way.

In the end I plan to have about 3000 organizations, plus however many comments I might have, maybe 20 per organization(estimates).

Which of these three options for the schema seem most reasonable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look up third normal form for some insight on how to structure a relational dbms.

However, you should probably have a couple tables, and each table would have an ID

A) Organization table with the organization name etc.

B) Address Table with a reference to the Organization ID (that way you can have multiple addresses to one organization)

C) Review Table with a foreign key reference to the Organization ID and User ID

D) A table of Users, with their password probably as a hash.

By refering back to the organization ID you can have a 1:MANY relationship, 1 Organization can have multiple addresses and reviews.

You only need about 4 tables from what I see, and if organizations to address is a 1:1 relationship you could just put the address in the organization table, although that's a little lazy and could bite you later.

Your comment table would have all your comments, and you would use the foreign keys to fetch reviews for a user or a organization. E.g. "Select * from Table_Reviews WHERE Organization_id = 10". If you look up ID=10 in the Organization table, you know who the review was for.

Comment: thanks for the answer...thanks for the tip about password hashing. is there a predefined php function for this (like the one in java) or is this something I make up?